# How to build a loop for converting entires of categorical columns to numerical values in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, numeric

I have a Pandas data frame with several columns, with some columns comprising categorical entries. I am 'manually' converting these entries to numerical values. For example,

```
df['gender'] = pd.Series(df['gender'].factorize()[0])
df['race'] = pd.Series(df['race'].factorize()[0])
df['city'] = pd.Series(df['city'].factorize()[0])
df['state'] = pd.Series(df['state'].factorize()[0])
```

If the number of columns is huge, this method is obviously inefficient. Is there a way to do this by constructing a loop over all columns (only those columns with categorical entries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) by columns in variable `cols`:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(['category']).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.factorize()[0])
```

EDIT:

Your solution should be simplify:

```
for column in df.select_dtypes(['category']):
    df[column] = df[column].factorize()[0]
```

Comment: Thank you.  The method show below also works fine.

Comment: @Nanda - Sure, also `pr.Series` should be removed.

Comment: Is there a reason why pd.Series should be removed? It works fine for my setup.

Comment: @Nanda - because if not default index `print (df.index)` is not `RangeIndex` your solution return NaNs.

Comment: @Nanda - Your solution working, because `RangeIndex` in `df`

Comment: Alright!  Got your point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following, which seems to work fine:

```
for column in df.select_dtypes(['category']):
    df[column] = pd.Series(df[column].factorize()[0])
```

where 'category' could be 'bool', 'object', etc.